# Query ATUALIZAR tabela inteira a partir do COUNT (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Olá,

Sou novo na área de programação e tenho uma leve experiência com banco de dados.
Gostaria de um help, já que não encontrei algum caso que pareça com o meu aqui.

Cenário: Estou montando um ambiente de oficinas com alunos, onde: **OFICINA** (que contem tabelas customizadas) ---> (**gera**)--->>> Alunos (associados pela ID da OFICINA nas tabelas customizadas).
Um registro PAI gera Registros FILHOS, só que preciso que no banco de dados, através de uma `PROCEDURE`, o mesmo realize a contagem destes registros filhos e atualize um campo com a contagem em todos os registros PAIS de acordo com a `query`. Estou utilizando a seguinte `query` (MYSQL):

```
update calls_cstm cc, calls c, insof_lista_presenca lp,
 (select count(distinct lp.name) count from insof_lista_presenca lp, calls c
    where lp.data_inicio = DATE(lp.data_hora_inicio)
    and lp.reference_id = c.id
    and lp.deleted = 0
    and c.deleted =0
     group by lp.evento_id)
     as count 
    set cc.total_inscritos_c = count
    where cc.id_c = c.id
    and c.deleted = 0
    and c.status = 'Planned'
    and c.direction = 'Inbound';
```

Acontece que esta `query` está gravando no campo que quero o primeiro registro, não esta gravando nos registros PAIS restantes. Em outras palavras só esta repetindo o primeiro registro. Resultado da `query` por SELECT:

```
# count, evento_id, data_inicio
2, 20-0013, 2020-01-04
2, 20-0014, 2020-01-04
2, 20-0015, 2020-01-05
2, 20-0017, 2020-01-04
4, 20-0020, 2020-01-04
2, 20-0021, 2020-01-06
2, 20-0021, 2020-01-07
```

A contagem em si esta certa, no entanto, só acontece o que citei acima. 
Acredito que meu `UPDATE` está errado...

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tente passar toda a subquey para o `set`: `... set cc.total_inscritos_c = (select ...`

Comment: Se é um campo calculado a partir de outros dados do banco ele não deve existir como um campo físico de seu banco. Caso julgue necessário facilitar a vida dos usuários você pode criar uma `view` contendo este campo calculado. Para mais detalhes veja o processo de normalização de dados.

Comment: @Costamilam o resultado é o mesmo pois o filtro acontece no where, se vc perceber tenho um filtro do filtro... e como o sistema que estou editando é open, este não possui views para usar... o acesso é direto no banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido! Encontrei a solução inserindo `JOIN ... ON`, segue a solução abaixo:

```
UPDATE calls_cstm cc
  JOIN ( SELECT lp.reference_id
              , count(lp.name) AS sum_attr
           FROM insof_lista_presenca lp , calls c
           where  lp.deleted = 0
           and lp.reference_id = c.id
           and c.deleted = 0
           and c.status = 'Planned'
           and c.direction = 'Inbound'
          GROUP BY lp.reference_id
       ) r
    ON r.reference_id = cc.id_c
   SET cc.total_inscritos_c = r.sum_attr
   WHERE cc.id_c in (select c.id from calls c);
```